# html2canvas with Angular not working as intended

Tags: angular, typescript, html2canvas

I need a second pair of eyes to find out why html2canvas is not working. I am unsure what I'm missing here. I have went over this several times and it shouldn't be this hard. I'm afraid its not being implemented correctly somehow. I will provide all I can. any assistance would be great! All I want to do is make sure it works and I am trying to do a simple task of displaying an div with an id when I click a button. Right now nothing happens when I click the button as if it's not implemented correctly

**HTML**

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
<h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>

<button (click)="clickMe()">Open html2canvas screen shot</button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';


clickMe() {
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
 }
```

**Node Modules**

[image]

**angular.json**

```
  "scripts": [
          "node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your console output. If it has a error like `ERROR TypeError: html2canvas_1.default is not a function` try to change your package importing as following:

```
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

Comment: I am getting in code 'This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/node_modules/html2canvas/dist/types/index")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)'

Comment: A minimal reproducable example on codesandbox or stackblitz would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try it, it works for me

```
h2c: any = html2canvas;
  captureScreen()
  {
    this.h2c(document.body).then((canvas) => {
      this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = 'Screenshot.png';
      this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
    });
  }
```